# Camera Calibration Principle Point Equals Zero

Tags: camera-calibration

I am using the [Caltech Tool](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/example.html) to calibrate my high precision camera. After all the steps done without a mistake, I got the output of:

```
Calibration results (with uncertainties):

Focal Length:          fc = [ 19492.53297   19388.55257 ] � [ 525.74266   512.39590 ]
Principal point:       cc = [ 2148.07762   -224.68443 ] � [ 0.00000   0.00000 ]
Skew:             alpha_c = [ 0.00000 ] � [ 0.00000  ]   => angle of pixel axes = 90.00000 � 0.00000 degrees
Distortion:            kc = [ -0.83041   11.44633   0.01176   -0.01231  0.00000 ] � [ 0.31872   5.17178   0.02315   0.00453  0.00000 ]
Pixel error:          err = [ 1.70741   1.96577 ]

Note: The numerical errors are approximately three times the standard deviations (for reference).
```

Now that I want to  construct my K matrix which is:

```
[fx, s, cx]
[0, fy, cy]
[0, 0, 1]
```

so in my case this would be:

```
def get_camera_intrinsic():
    K = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype='float64')
    K[0, 0], K[0, 2] = 525.74266, 0  
    K[1, 1], K[1, 2] = 512.39590, 0  
    K[2, 2] = 1.
    return K
```

which makes no sense to me because principle point being 0 is weird:

```
Principal point:       cc = [ 2148.07762   -224.68443 ] � [ 0.00000   0.00000 ]
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Here is a sample image I used during the calibration. Due to size issues it will take some time for me to resize the images, change their file types to upload all of them here.

[image]

Comment: The principle point is `[ 2148.07762   -224.68443 ]`, not `[0, 0]`. The `�` are actually supposed to be `+/-`. The weird thing is rather the boresight `y` being negative. Also, your focal length `fc` seems too big. How big are your pixels? My guess is that your calibration wasn't successful. Just because the program didn't throw any errors doesn't mean you got good results.

Comment: My resolution is 4K, since I am using a high-end camera.

Comment: Yes, but that does not define the pixel sizes. You could capture 4K video with pixels as large as cars if you had an camera large enough (theoretically).

Comment: Why would my pixels be extraordinarily big? I mean, it's Basler Ace camera, industrial, typical high-end.

Comment: I'm am sorry, my comment seems to have been misleading. I meant the size of your pixels is not dependent on the resolution (4K). The focal length value `fc` (in pixels) is given as focal length (in `mm`) divided by pixel size (in `mm/p`). Therefore, if you have *very* small pixels, it means `fc` will be large.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but is this something I can change, in anyway? Like, let's assume that is the case (that my pixels are very small) thus my fc is very large, isn't the calibration still valid? Should I rely on these values in the output?

Comment: It means the `fc` values could be correct, and your calibration could be valid. To make sure you would have to go read your camera's datasheet, and see if it makes sense. What worries me is that your `y` principle point is negative (`-224.684`). It could be helpful if you add the chessboard images you used with the extracted corners (Figure 3 on [this](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/example.html) website).